# gcc compile time and memory usage changing as array size in source code changes

Tags: gcc

This is gcc 4.4.6 on Linux.

Here's the behavior

**bizarre.c**

```
double a[500000000];

main() {
}
```

If I compile this using:

```
gcc bizarre.c
```

Then the compiler uses 4G of memory, and takes a long time.

If I make the array size 50000000, the the compilation takes considerably less memory and time.

It's like the compiler is executing the code that it's compiling.

I realize that creating a humongous array this way might not be best practice, but any explanations?

Comment: You compiling as 32 or 64 bit executable?

Comment: no optimization flags? you are going to run into a  stack overflow more than likely... with optimization turned on, this variable is probably eliminated if using optimization higher than -O0

Comment: @0A0D: this array is getting stuffed in the `.bss` section anyway, no stack involved...

Comment: 64bit. No stack overflow, as it's a global.

Comment: A friend in the gcc community suggested _report it to [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)_.

Comment: @sarnold: So you expect the output file to be in the order of 1GB?

Comment: @leppie, no, because the `BSS` section simply stores the _sizes_ of the data objects to be instantiated with zero bytes. The version with one `0` removed compiles to `8355` bytes on my system, and I'd expect the version with the `0` put back to compile to within 32 bytes of this size -- probably identical size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known linker bug related to --build-id, now fixed on mainline.  See  http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12451  Some distros took an earlier patch of Nick's that needlessly calculated a checksum over .bss, requiring the .bss section to be allocated and zeroed.  Complain to your distro.